# Rails - validates_uniqueness_of: access duplicate item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic Rails model with two properties, *name* and *code*.  I have **validates_uniqueness_of** for the *code* property.  However, I'd like to customize the :message to show the *name* of the duplicate.  Is there any way to access this duplicate item?

For example, say I first enter a record called **Expired** with code **EXP**.  Then I enter **Experience** with code **EXP**.  I would like the :message to say something like "Code already taken by Expired".

```
> m1 = Model.new(:name => 'Expired', :code => 'EXP')
> m2 = Model.new(:name => 'Experience', :code => 'EXP')
> m1.save!
> m2.save!

validates_uniqueness_of :code,
  :message => "Code already taken by #{duplicate.name}"
```

Is there any built-in Rails construct that holds the duplicate object so that I can access it like I do in the :message?  Or is there any other way I can run code to determine the duplicate when this validation gets triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'd have to write a custom validation method. Something like:

```
def validate
   model = Model.first(:conditions => {:code => self.code})
   unless model.blank? && (self.id != model.id)
     errors.add_to_base "Code already taken by #{model.name}"
   end
end
```

Comment: Thought I'd add that we need to add logic to make sure _self.id_ is not the same as _model.id_.  Otherwise we'll never be able to update an existing item (unless that's the behaviour you want).

Answer (score 2):

As per @j but as a validation callback and target the message specifically to the failing attribute

```
validate do |model|
   duplicate = Model.first(:conditions => {:code => model.code})
   if duplicate
     model.errors.add :code, "already taken"
   end
end
```